# How to Pin "moving" data within the terminal similar to test-netconnection?

Tags: powershell

I've created a script that checks the last modified date of a file and based on the result does some actions, I've also got it to output various responses to console via Write-Host, however this data "moves" up the console as a new update comes through, and yes although I've also got it saving out to a log file, I'd like to use the console as a "dashboard" of sorts, keeping only the last update there.

My question is, is it possible to have a selected piece of information stay pinned to either the bottom or the top of the console? similar to how Test-NetConnection pins to the top of the console, or when updating/downloading modules the terminal highlights at the top.

It might involve a function with static text with the variable for the current update, ie:

======= File Checker =======

Last Update: $CurrentUpdate
Last Note  : $CurrentNote

============================
Where only the variables get updates, the rest stays static/pinned in place.

As an example?.

Tips in the right direction is what I'm looking for
Thanks,

Comment: Would it have to be added into like a switch function; and the switch function has an auto update?.

Comment: With .NET `System.Console` class you have more control, like set position etc.

Comment: Ok so I found a solution that works well for my project.

essentially:

while($true) { 
cls
<do stuff>
start-sleep -seconds <time>
}

it clears the screen at the start of each loop cycle, does stuff, and that way I can get the update, pass the newly updated variables to the dashboard. Works a treat. thanks.